# Why's my solution wrong for reversing an integer?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, debugging, integer

I need to reverse an integer, in this case, `123` should come out to `321`.  I'm converting the int to string, reversing the string, converting it back to an int, and then returning it but some how I'm getting the `error`.

What's a good way to solve this problem?

Here's my code:

```
public static int solution(int x) {
    String s = Integer.toString(x);
    String result = " ";
    int ans = 0;

    for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += s.charAt(i);
    }

    ans = Integer.parseInt(result);

    return ans;
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    int x = 123;

    System.out.print(solution(x)) 
}
```

Here's my `error`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 321"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at Node.solution(Node.java:28)
at Node.main(Node.java:47)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not add a white space at the beginning:

```
String result = " ";
```

Use empty string

```
String result = "";
```

---

And, not related to the question, you can also achieve it by this:

```
int x = 123;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(x);
int y = Integer.parseInt(stringBuilder.reverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in redundant conversions to string and vice versa.
Python code (note leading zero eliminating):

```
def rev(x):
    res = 0
    while (x > 0):
        res = res * 10 + x % 10
        x  = x // 10
    return res

print(rev(9801), rev(120))
>>> 1089 21
```